# how to insert data in current logged in user's account?

Tags: php, mysql

i want insert data to current logged in user i changed 4 to session id but error please help me how to store id in session and use here

**login.php**

```
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
```

**home.php**

```
<?php
//Get current user ID from session
$userId = 4;
//Get user data from database
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $userId");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>
```

Comment: Where's your insert query and where's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Directly add the value to session array.It will updated with session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']  = 4;
$userId =$_SESSION['user_id']
```

Answer (score 0):

executing the function call 'session_id()' returns the id of the session for the vistor, the session is actually a file kept in a directory of your server, the session_id will point to this file in all instances that I've personally seen.

to actually access the session you need to use $_SESSION to set and read data :) Happy Coding!